# Python - Best approach for making over 100,000 requests and storing to database

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, asynchronous, web-scraping

There is data that I'm scraping from many different requests.

Up until now, I've used multithreading and the requests library to retrieve the necessary and then loading them into an sqlite database. with approximately the following approach:

```
p = Pool(processes=8)
for x in range(start_1,end_1):
    for y in range(start_2,end_2):
        entry_list = p.starmap(get_data, [(x , y , z) for z in range(start, end)]):
        ### get_data makes the request and retruns a tuple of (x,y,z,data)
        for entry in entry list:
            cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Database (attrib_1, attrib_2, attrib_3, data )
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)''', entry )
```

This approach is very slow (will take days to make all of the requests on my machine). After doing a little research I have seen that there are alternatives to multithreading for this kind of problem, such as asynchronous requests. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about this approach and whether or not it's appropriate, far less how to implement it.

Any advice on how to complete this task efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is already "asynchronous". If you intend to perform an asynchronous request inside `get_data`, it would be sensible to share the code for that function.

Answer (score 0):

Since your program is I/O bound, look at event loops. True multi-threading is broken in Python because of the global interpreter lock (GIL).

Look at [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) (available since Python 3.4) and/or [Twisted](https://github.com/twisted/twisted).